# replace('\n','') not working for series of \n\n\n

Tags: python, html

For a pre downloaded html file,i want to replace multiple \n with a new line.
i have tried,
`html = html.replace('\n','')`, but doesn't work.
Is there any other work around?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: `\n` can be strange.  End of lines is problematic between unix and dos systems.  Technically, end of lines are `\r\n` which is a carriage return line feed combination.  if you want to eliminate everything, do `html = html.replace("\n","").replace("\r","")`  Maybe that's what you want.

Comment: issue resolved -     html = html.replace('\\r','').replace('\\n','').replace('\\t','')

Answer (score 1):

The line drop may be represented by `\r`

```
print (html.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""))
```